# JW Player - video from youtube is still loading

Tags: video, youtube, jwplayer, jwplayer7

I would like to use JW Player 7 with youtube video. My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="jwplayer.js" ></script>
  <script>jwplayer.key="MY-SECRET-LICENSE-KEY";</script>
</head>
  <body>
  <div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var playerInstance = jwplayer("myElement");
    playerInstance.setup({
    file: "https//www.youtube.com/watch?v=ApN73TUVMEU",
    primary: 'html5'
    });
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Player shows up, but the video never starts - it's just loading and loading. There is no errors in console or player. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: **Read tag descriptions before adding!**

Comment: That code looks fine. Do you have a link?

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer Nope, I just run it on localhost (btw. I used different browsers e.g. Chrome, Firefox, IE and all of them had the same problem).

Comment: Can you put something up? As you can see, or example works fine - http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1406725-youtube-video-embed